# Does the Arizal really say Yeshu was the reincarnation of Eisav?

Tags: christianity, arizal, reincarnation

[This web article](http://koshertorah.com/PDF/Orthodox%20Missionaries.pdf), on page 4, states that the Arizal taught in Sefer HaGilgulim, chapter 67, that Yeshu (Jesus) was the reincarnation of Eisav. I tried looking for the Sefer HaGilgulim online, but I couldn't find it.

Can someone clear this up for me? Did the Arizal actually teach this? Here's the original quote from the article:

> Indeed, according to the teachings of the Ari’zal, revealed to him by none other than
>   Eliyahu HaNavi (Elijah), Yeshu was none other than the reincarnation of Esav,
>   the brother of Ya’aqov Avinu (ref. Sefer HaGilgulim of the Ari’zal, chapter 67).

Comment: It's right there on Hebrewbooks twice http://hebrewbooks.org/45024 or http://hebrewbooks.org/23822

Comment: OK I didn't think of checking HebrewBooks but that still doesn't answer my question. The copies of Sefer HaGilgulim you linked do not have a chapter 67.

Comment: I recall heard this in the name of Abravanel.

Comment: @ezra I found the Shem MiShmuel quoting it in the name of the Ariza"l and a few places quoting it in the name of the Abravanel. I found the the sefer on Otzar HaChachmah that claims to have up to chapter 73 so it might be there, but I don't have a key. https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?5978&

Comment: So did we locate the source or not? My rabbi couldn't find it in Sefer Gilgulim

Comment: A similar idea is in the Ari's Pri Etz Chaim: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14173&st=&pgnum=91&hilite=.

Comment: The question assumes reincarnation is in the Torah when it is not.

Comment: @TurkHill How in the world does the question assume that? The question was about the Arizal.

Comment: @Harel13 i answered based on your comment

Comment: @DoubleAA The editions of Sefer HaGilgulim on Hebrewbooks.org are not the long manuscript. That long manuscript (which if I recall has 72 chapters) is mentioned in Shem HaGadolim by the Chida z"l. I have a copy in my library and will try to look it up when I have a moment. Generally, the citations that Rabbi Ariel Bar Tzadok provides are accurate.

Comment: @KennyXiong In the context of your comment that confirmation or rejection of the idea that the Ari z"l taught Yeshu was an incarnation of Eisav "is very important" to you, the citation from Pri Eitz Chaim is confirmation. But the important thing to keep in mind with that teaching of the Ari z"l is that, like Eisav, the head of Yeshu (his source, but not his teachings) are from the side of Holiness. And this is also in keeping with the censored portion of the Mishneh Torah, Laws of Kings, Chapter 11:4-7. https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.11.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, at the end of chapter 67 in Sefer HaGilgulim it brings exactly what was cited in your question from Rabbi Ariel Bar Tzadok.

The Ari z"l, as quoted in a hand-written note from Rabbi Chaim Vital shown here below, is actually making several source references.

The Mitzri mentioned in the heading is referring to the unnamed Mitzri also mentioned in [Shemot 2:11-12](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2.11-12?lang=bi&aliyot=0). This is the individual that Moshe Rabbeinu killed by using one of G-d's names. In the commentaries there, it mentions that Moshe actually checked to see if any important descendants would come from this person before killing him.

The Ari z"l also connects the descendants of this individual with Kayin, who murdered his brother, Hevel in the beginning of the book of Bereshit. It was via this association that the Ari makes reference to his ultimate judgement of being immersed in boiling excrement in Gehinom as discussed in tractate [Gittin 57a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.57a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). This particular judgement falls on those who mock the Sages, something specifically mentioned in connection with Yeshu both in his early youth (*see for example the Nag Hammadi text of the Infancy Gospel of Thomas*) and later, as he grew up like is discussed in connection with his treatment of his teacher, Rabbi Yehoshua ben Perachiyah in [Sanhedrin 107b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.107b.12-14?lang=bi).

This is also discussed in the [Zohar 2:12b:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.2.12b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which also connects this person to Eisav.

But then the Ari z"l goes further and says his pedigree is the same as the person mentioned in [VaYikra 24:10-11](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.24.10-11?lang=bi&aliyot=0) and  his commonly known name is actually referenced through the *Roshei Teivot* (first letters) in the posuk from [VaYikra 24:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.24.16?lang=bi&aliyot=0), which in reversed order spells out *Yeshu*.

The image from my copy of the book follows:

[image: Sefer HaGilgulim end of Chapter 67]

Comment: If this is indeed the case, how does Ari HaKadosh reconcile this with the usual association of that particular person and Bilhaam? Or is there s link between Esav and Bilhaam I'm unaware of?

Comment: @JoshK See the link to the Zohar in my answer. It’s discussed there and is also alluded to in the citation from Gittin.

Comment: תדה רבה ממש, Yaakov!

Comment: ????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: @JoshK In case you didn’t notice, using the tzeruf of Yitzchok Avinu, the transformation of Gevurah, רוע המצר״י becomes שוע הנצר״י, an alternate of his common name. And this can also be read הנצר י״שוע.

Answer (score 3):

As @Harel13 commented: In the Book, Pri Eitz Chaim, [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14173&st=&pgnum=91&hilite=), (the Teachings of Isaac Luria / Arizal, recorded by his student Chayim Vital), it says the following:

[image: Hebrew text]

> "It's found in another place: It's spelled / it says עשי״ו [Esav], because he
> was reincarnated into ישוע [Yeshua]. [I think he's trying to point out the the
> letters in both names are the same, only rearranged.]  He was a student of
> R' Yehoshua ben Prachiah, and since R' prachiah pushed him away with
> two hands, and he was punished, as it says there. And that's why when
> Chushem, son of Dan, killed Esav, he chopped off his head and the head
> rolled into the cave and it was buried there with Yakov, because the
> holiness was only in the head, that's why he was buried there."

Comment: Chosem?, I always thought it was Chushim

Comment: @sam you might be right

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%A8%22%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%92 text at Wikisource

Comment: re: the bounty: This of course opens the old can of worms if Yishu the disciple of Yehoshua ben Perachia is the infamous Jesus.

Comment: @Mordechai there is a debate about that?

Comment: Yehosua ben Perachia was about 100 years before the founder of Christianity.

Comment: @Mordechai so then what's the debate? How can it be possible for anyone to think otherwise?